# Forcing Windows to use specific NIC cards

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, network-shares

I have two desktop computers sitting next to one another, a fair distance from a wireless access point. (C1 & C2, respectively)  C1 runs windows 7 pro and C2 Windows 10 Home.  Unfortunately, I do not get great wifi speeds (fair distance), however that is the only internet connection I have currently.

As I often share large files between these computers, I have decided I do not want to use my distant wireless access point for networking these two, rather I have setup a redundant spare wired router to handle base traffic for these computers.  Ideally, this router would be set up as a repeater for this wireless signal to improve the connection, however I do not want to repeat the signal since I am the only one with such a long distance.

So to clear up what we have:

```
    C1 & C2 Wifi Adapter Nic                      C1 & C2 Onboard NIC

            Internet                                Base Router
               |                                      /      \ 
          Wifi Router                                C1      C2
          /        \  
         C1        C2
```

Herein lies the problem:
When C1 or C2 have both wifi and wired NICs enabled:  C1 and C2 try to use the wired connection to access the internet, and all DNS and connectivity fails since there is no connection.  Windows shares transmit at about 1mpbs.

When C1 or C2 have the wifi nic disabled:  the wired connectivity works at high speeds (25Mbps+) perfectly but no internet access

Here is what I would like to solve:
c1 & c2  use the wired nic for only windows sharing and any upnp connections not on the wifi nic

c1 & c2 use the wifi nic only for internet tcp/ip connectivity

Food for thought:  I have set up the wired nic to be on 192.168.1.xxx and the wireless nic is on the 192.168.0.xxx net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your base (wired) router, you need to disable its routing functionality.  Turn it into basically a dumb switch -- no DHCP, no NAT, no port forwarding, etc.

For the wired connection on each computer, set up a static IP address, or you can just leave it at DHCP and let each computer auto-assign an address in the 169.254.x.x range.  In the DNS address box, use the IP address of your wireless router.  Make sure there is no default gateway set (if using an auto-assigned address there won't be one).

Finally, on your computer with two connections, make sure that the wireless adapter is the LOWEST in the precedence order (so it always gets searched last to resolve addresses).

You should now have a scenario where your computer can be connected to both networks and will auto-select the one that has the resource it's looking for (that is, Internet traffic will go via wireless, and internal connectivity will use the wired connection).

Note that if both computers have two connections, both will have an IP address on each network.  If you find that they're still trying to use wireless to communicate with each other, you might need to manually update your hosts file with the wired address of the other computer.  That means you'll need a static address, but it won't rely on DNS to resolve addresses.  Windows routes the traffic based on the IP.

Comment: This solution works, however when I restart the computer, all the settings revert to how it was previously.    I have attempted to use the powershell to configure precedences and lower the `InterfaceMetric`.  Do you have any suggestions, as that is still only working intermittently.

Comment: @hawkhorrow; The computer that reverts the settings... Is it just the Win10 machine or both of them?

Comment: It was from Windows 10

Comment: Every time I also disable or re-enable either NIC, upon them not working I also need to restart and go through a whole headache to get it working again